# Перенос запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где здесь нужна запятая - перед первым или перед вторым тире? И также где можно почитать про перенос запятой после второго тире?

Манжеты успешно применяются в пищевой и фармацевтической промышленности, поскольку материалы, используемые в манжетах — фторопласт и нержавеющая сталь — имеют соответствующие сертификаты.

Comment: про перенос запятой?

Comment: Да, может эта тема здесь уже поднималась или в интернете есть ресурсы...

Comment: Как эту тему назвать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Манжеты успешно применяются в пищевой и фармацевтической промышленности, поскольку материалы, используемые в манжетах, — фторопласт и нержавеющая сталь — имеют соответствующие сертификаты.

**Пояснение**

Вопрос о постановке запятой и тире решается **в трех темах**: обобщающие слова при однородных членах, обособление приложений и вставные конструкции, при этом возможно: 1) поглощение одного тире; 2) перенос запятой. Все эти варианты в принципе рассматриваются в правилах Лопатина и Розенталя, но тем не менее всегда вызывают вопросы.

К примеру, вставка всегда обособляется двумя тире, в этом случае решается вопрос о переносе запятой. Обособленные приложения могут встраиваться в структуру сложного предложения и обособляться одним тире.

В заданном примере, действительно, можно сослаться на лопатинский пример из темы обобщающих слов: Всё, что могло приглушить звуки, — ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель — Григ давно убрал из дома. (Кстати, вместо первого тире здесь иногда пишут двоеточие). Но хотя эта тема относится к  "Обобщающим словам при однородных членах", ее можно решить в общем виде **по методу вставки** (именно тогда вместо двоеточия используется тире).

Итак, при вставке ставятся **оба тире и решается вопрос о запятой**. Перенос запятой делается в тех случаях, когда на месте вставки была запятая, относящаяся к структуре предложения (однородные члены, деепричастный оборот,   ССП или СПП), например: Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала.

Но запятая **не переносится, если перед вставкой находится обособленный член предложения, не входящий в её состав**:  День, **который она провела в Москве,** – потом она часто вспоминала об этом – был тёплым, солнечным. Увидеть и услышать писателя для меня, **провинциала**, – я тогда работал в Сибири – было необычайным счастьем.

В нашем предложении именно этот вариант (вставка/однородный ряд не входит в состав обособленного члена, а относится к слову "материалы"): Манжеты успешно применяются в пищевой и фармацевтической промышленности, поскольку материалы, **используемые в манжетах**, — фторопласт и нержавеющая сталь — имеют соответствующие сертификаты.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1):

*Манжеты успешно применяются в пищевой и фармацевтической промышленности, поскольку материалы, используемые в манжетах,— фторопласт и нержавеющая сталь — имеют соответствующие сертификаты*. Нужна запятая перед первым тире: она закрывает причастный оборот *используемые в манжетах*. Далее у Вас в предложении идут однородные члены предложения, имеющие значение попутного замечания, они выделяются с двух сторон тире. Ср.: *Всё, что могло приглушить звуки, — ковры, портьеры и мягкую мебель — Григ давно убрал из дома*.